# Using "dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown" execute a shell command before shutdown

Tags: pi-zero-w, shutdown

In `/boot/config.txt` I did put

```
dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,active_low=1,gpio_pull=up
```

Now if I short GPIO 3 - the Pi does shutdown immediately.

But how can I run some shell script before shutting down via GPIO 3 shorting?

Comment: upd: I should say not "immediately", but quite quickly - the pi does shutdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a systemd service ([example](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/fake-hwclock.service?h=fake-hwclock)) which runs your script shortly before shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown actions

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path/to/script

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

`ExecStart` action is set to a program which finishes right away, so you need `RemainAfterExit=true` to keep the service running from the systemd point of view. Don't forget to enable your service with `sudo systemctl enable my.service`

If you need to distinguish between shutdown and reboot, one possible solution is to check which target is active from inside your script. Try running `systemctl is-active poweroff.target` and `systemctl is-active reboot.target`, and analyze its return code (0=active, 1=inactive) or output (it outputs "active"/"intactive" as a string).

As an alternative, try the following service (it should run only on reboot, not on a power-off):

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown actions
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=reboot.target
Conflicts=reboot.target

# The rest is the same as above
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path/to/script

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Comment: Thank @Dmitry, is there a way to run this on shutdown only, and not on reboot. Now this custom script even runs on reboot

Comment: this helped me to run on shutdown only
`ExecStop=/bin/bash -c 'systemctl list-jobs | grep -Eq 'reboot.target.*start' || sudo /home/admin/bin/scripts/script.sh'`

Comment: @VextoR: Isn't that what the first example does??

Comment: @Seamus the 1st one runs even on reboot, not just shutdown

Comment: @VextoR: Ah, I see... I'm sure Dmitry will acknowledge & update.